# Do some IoT devices connect to your wifi without you knowing it?

Tags: wifi, botnet, iot

I keep hearing about refrigerators and automated vacuum cleaners being targeted, but do the owners manually configure these devices to connect to their wifi network or do the devices have a work around?  Are there any IoT devices that are not connected to your WiFi and are those of any security concern besides possibly becoming part of a botnet?

Answer (score 4):

The owner normally has to manually configure the device to connect to their wifi, since (a) the IoT device can't automatically figure out which wireless network belongs to the device's owner, and (b) even if it did, it can't connect unless it can figure out the password.

MechMK1 mentions the possibility of the device connecting automatically to open Wifi Access Points. Although this is possible, its unlikely for an IoT device to be configured to do so, since as MechMK1 mentions, this would probably be illegal.

> are those of any security concern besides possibly becoming part of a botnet?

Of course. There is a lot an attacker could do after compromising an IoT device, depending on the devices capabilities. For example, if you have a home security system connected to the internet, the hacker could use any security cameras to spy on you. Or the consequences could possibly be more lethal. For example, a hacked internet connected smart oven could perhaps be used to start a fire.

Answer (score 3):

#### It's possible in some circumstances.

If your access point is configured to be open, meaning no authentication whatsoever, then a device may attempt to connect to it without your consent.

If your access point is configured to use any kind of authentication (WEP, WPA/2/3), then a device cannot connect to your AP without the proper authentication key (usually a password for home setups).

Is this something you should worry about?

Not really, unless you have an AP that is configured to be open. In that case, you have bigger problems.

Is this legal?

I don't know. My gut feeling says no, but my gut feeling isn't a lawyer. You will have to ask a lawyer in your state or country.